# matplotlib make legend without frame and draggable

Tags: matplotlib

I just noticed that if I set a plot legend to be without frame and draggable, as a result I get indeed no frame but it is not draggable.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10), label = 'range(10)')
plt.legend(frameon = False).draggable(state = True)
plt.show()
```

I'm not totally sure how I should use the legend command to get it being draggable but with the above input, if I do not specify 'frameon = False' or if I set 'frameon = True' the legend is indeed draggable in the resulting plot.

Comment: I've tried the code as stated above. The legend does not have a frame and I can drag it. I'm not sure what the problem is because this is exactly what you want right? Using python 2.7

Comment: using python 2.7, matplotlib 1.1.1

Comment: My matplotlib version is 1.2.1